# EF LINQ Group By and Sum

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to do select with group by and sum while selecting other columns using LINQ and i come out with this

```
var inputList = from c in db.InputItem
                             join o in db.ItemsDefinition on c.ItemsDefinitionID equals o.ItemsDefinitionID
                             group c by new { c.ItemsDefinitionID, o.ItemsAName } into g
                             select new
                             {
                                 Name = g.Key,
                                 Sum = g.Sum(c => c.Quantity)
                             };
```

what I'm trying to do is to preform this SQL statement

```
Select i.ItemsDefinitionID,
       ID.ItemsAName, 
       sum(Quantity) as avialable
from InputItem i 
Left Outer Join ItemsDefinition ID On i.ItemsDefinitionID=ID.ItemsDefinitionID
group by i.ItemsDefinitionID,ID.ItemsAName
```

Warm Thanks

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this way too:

```
var inputList = d.InputItem
    .GroupBy(s =>s.ItemsDefinitionID, s.ItemsDefinition.AName)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        ItemsDefinitionID=g.Key.ItemsDefinitionID,
        Name = g.Key.AName,
        Available= g.Sum(s =>s.Quantity),
       
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to do manual joins in EF if your relationships are properly defined in the model.

This query will suffice

```
var result = db.ItemsDefinition.Select(id => new { id.ItemsDefinitionID, 
        id.ItemsAName, Quantity = id.Items.Sum(i => i.Quantity) });
```

Either leave the SQL generation to EF or stop using EF. There's no point in using an ORM if you keep worrying about the queries it will generate.